# How to add close button to every item in toolstrip

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I have ToolStrip control with ToolStripButtons in Winforms. Every item has Text and Image. How to add "close button" in the right corner of item like in a browser or notepad++?

Comment: Any answer that contains more than: "just create a button and add it tot he controls of the toolstrip" will require from you to post your code and see how far you are

Comment: That's an owner-drawn (`TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`) `SysTabControl32`. A TabControl, not a Button.